# Using titleps with unnumbered sections

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titleps

When I use unnumbered sections, my `titleps` headers seem to inherit the section name and numbering from the previous section:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{fancy}{
    \headrule
    \sethead{}{\itshape\sectiontitle}{}
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[5-8]
\clearpage

\section*{Unnumbered section}
\lipsum[9-12]

\end{document}
```

In the example, the first two sections get the proper headers, but the third section gets the same header as the second. This also seems to happen to my bibliography (I'm using `biblatex`). How can I get the name of starred sections and bibliographies in the header?

Comment: You can set `\sectionmark{Unnumbered section}` after that `\section*` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire [`titlesec` module](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) discourages the use of starred version of sectional units. As such, their usage seems may cause unexpected/unwanted results anyway. In this case, however, you're better off issuing a manual `\sectionmark{<title>}` to update the display in the headers. The process can be automated with the help of [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titleps,xparse}
\newpagestyle{fancy}{
    \headrule
    \sethead{}{\itshape\sectiontitle}{}
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {{% \section*
      \oldsection*{#3}% \section*[.]{..}
      \sectionmark{#3}%
    }}{% \section
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
    }%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Numbered section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage

\section*{Unnumbered section}
\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```